# Unable to use aspect from class library

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I have a web UI project and a JavaFX UI project that both reference a class library that contains all the common logic : JPA repos, services, entities, etc.  Each UI project has local logging aspects that work great, here's an example of my ControllerLogger which logs calls to all controller methods :

The aspect :

```
@Aspect
@Log4j2
public class ControllerLogger
{
    private LogEntryService les;

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.some.web.project.controller..*(..))")
    private void controllerMethods() {}

    @Before("controllerMethods()")
    public void logMethodCallWithParameters(JoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        //Logs at TRACE level using Log4J logger and LogEntryService
    }
}
```

The aspectJ config class (my understanding and my testing revealed that I cannot annotate the aspect with @Component and LogEntryService with @Autowired expecting it to be autowired correctly.  If that is not the case PLEASE let me know!):

```
@Configuration
public class AspectJConfiguration 
{
    @Bean
    public ControllerLogger controllerLogger(LogEntryService logEntryService)
    {
        var aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(ControllerLogger.class);
        aspect.setLogEntryService(logEntryService);

        return aspect;
    }
}
```

The AOP.xml file :

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="com.some.web.project..*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.some.web.project.logging.ControllerLogger"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

The VM arguments to make this work (with the referenced jars in the lib folder):

```
-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.8.jar -javaagent:lib/spring-instrument-5.3.16.jar --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This all works perfectly.  The JavaFX project has a similar setup for 5 different logging aspects and they all work great.  The issue arises when I try to use an aspect that lives in the class library project that both UI projects reference.  Here is what I tried :

The library aspect is exactly the same but has a different pointcut :

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.some.library.project.service..*(..))")
private void serviceMethods() {}
```

Added this to my web project's AOP.xml :

```
<aspect name="com.some.library.project.logging.ServiceLogger"/>
```

Finally added this bean to my web project's aspectJ config class :

```
@Bean
public ServiceLogger serviceLogger(LogEntryService logEntryService)
{
    var aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(ServiceLogger.class);
    aspect.setLogEntryService(logEntryService);

    return aspect;
}
```

When running the web project with this new aspect, I get the following exception :

```
Error creating bean with name 'serviceLogger' defined in class path resource [com/some/web/project/configuration/AspectJConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.some.library.project.logging.ServiceLogger]: Factory method 'serviceLogger' threw exception; nested exception is org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing com.some.library.project.logging.ServiceLogger: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.some.library.project.logging.ServiceLogger.aspectOf()
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why is spring not able to use an aspect defined in another jar?  Is this even possible?

Comment: It depends... If you use AspectJ and Spring you can perfectly use it, but then you use proxies. You are using loadtime weaving which means AspectJ is in control and thus you cannot use the autowiring.

Comment: If I remove the javaagent arguments then I get that same error for my local ControllerLogger aspect as well

Comment: Well there is no `aspectOf` method (as it clearly states) which means it probably hasn't been compiled with the aspectj compiler but just with the java compiler (which doesn't add themethod). But you don't need the factory method, you can just add `@Component` and `@Autowired` and it should work (however it will use proxies not loadtime weaving).

Comment: I do not agree with some of M. Deinum's statements, or maybe I am misinterpreting them. Spring AOP and AspectJ really are different beasts, we have to be careful not to mix up ideas, terminology and concepts. I would very much welcome a minimal reproducer project on GitHub and see for myself what is going on there. This question contains a lot of valuable information, but not enough for me to offer concrete advice (no pun intended).

Comment: I see what you did there XD.  This project has been YEARS in the making but I remember switching to load-time weaving just to get bloody unit tests to work.  I ended up putting try-catch blocks around my LogEntryService logging statements inside my aspects and switching back to compile time weaving which now works perfectly.  I no longer need the AspectJ config class, java agents, etc.  I can try to provide a MCVE if you want to look into it.

Comment: An MCVE is always a good start.

Comment: Please either add the promised MCVE, write your own comprehensive answer (not just that you gave up and used another approach) or, if the question became irrelevant to you now, delete it completely so others do not have to read it when looking for open questions, only to find out that an answer is no longer required.